# My mac and my PC don't show the same download speed

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, download, speed

I recently installed fiber optics in my home and when I did some tests with [nperf](https://www.nperf.com/fr/) I noticed that while connected to the same wifi and placed next to each other, my Mac and my PC didn't have the same download speed.

Result from my PC:
[image]

Result from my MAC:
[image]

I made the tests so that the two antennas were at the same location and I was the two time sitting at the same place.

My MAC is a Macbook Pro retina late 2013

On my PC I use the wifi card [TP Link TL-WDN4800](https://www.tp-link.com/fr/home-networking/adapter/tl-wdn4800/) which has a debit of 450 Mbps for 11n wifi. This is a debit of 56,25 Mops so I should have the same performances as my mac.

The card is connected to a PCIe x1 line, I tried to move it to the x16 slot connected directly to my CPU but the card isn't detected (and this shouldn't change anything since one PCIe line should be enough to carry 450Mbps)

I have absolutely no experience in networking does anybody have an idea of why I have those differences? What parameters could I try to tweak to use the full potential of my card?

Comment: 802.11n is really old equipment.  I suspect you are trying to compare apples to oranges (in other words the two machines are no where close to being comparable).

Comment: Obviously, the only thing I forgot to test is the answer to my question ^^' My PC is connected to my 5GHz wifi in n whereas my mac is connected to the same 5Ghz wifi in ac, I completely forgot this little letter, thanks

Comment: 8011.ac (Wi-Fi 5) is significantly faster than 802.11n (Wi-Fi 4). You should upgrade your wireless adapter it's a sever bottleneck.

Comment: Yep, it's already planned, I don't think I will wait for Christmas